# How to calculate min of values greater than average in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

i have index with keys "group" and "x", and i need to get min of the x values greater than average(x)*0.1 in buckets of "group".
Can i achieve this, using elasticsearch aggregations?

For example:

```
{"id":1,"group":"g1","x": 1}
{"id":2,"group":"g1","x": 10}
{"id":3,"group":"g1","x": 20}
{"id":4,"group":"g2","x": 5}
{"id":5,"group":"g2","x": 100}
{"id":6,"group":"g2","x": 200}
```

should return 10 for g1 (without 1 because 1 < 3.1) and 100 for g2, because 5 < 30.5

Comment: can you add a sample document

Comment: @jaspreetchahal, added above

Comment: It is not possible in single query. Using two queries first average can be calculated and then using appropriate document can be searched. Also  average can be calculated and stored at index time, this will allow data to be queried in single query